# php - Not able to display

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, output

I am trying to display data from mysql using php. Please find the code which I have used. I am only getting the field names in the output.  The referred table in the query containing more than 50 rows.
Please help to solve my issue...

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","ayrilmana");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT txn_amount,donated_by FROM tempe_txn");

echo "<table border='1'> 
<tr>
<th>txn_amount</th>
<th>donated_by</th>
</tr>";

if($result === FALSE){
    die(mysql_error()); 
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['txn_amount'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['donated_by'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: For one thing, you're using a mix of both `mysqli` and `mysql_`

Comment: What if you tried `$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tempe_txn");`